# How to convert this associative array to separated arrays containing the keys, but for the last nested level contain the values

Tags: php, laravel

I am given a key-value array that represents selections to filter by organization's hierarchy (`group`, `unit`, `department`, `team`), for example:

```
// dd($selections)
[
    "group2" => [
        "unit11" => [
            "department50" => [
                0 => "team10",
                1 => "team58"
             ],
        ],    
        "unit10" => [],
    ],

    "group5" => [
        "unit23" => [
            "department101" => []                
        ],
    ],    
]
```

Its structure is a bit different where each key represents the selection value, except for the last nested level which is the list of `team`s selected as the values, not the keys.

I need to build a query based on these selections to filter out the results. For the above example, the query would be similar to:

```
$fullQuery
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where("group", "=", 'group2')
            ->where("unit", "=", 'unit11')
            ->where("department", "=", 'department50')
            ->where("team", "=", 'team10')
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where("group", "=", 'group2')
            ->where("unit", "=", 'unit11')
            ->where("department", "=", 'department50')
            ->where("team", "=", 'team58')
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where("group", "=", 'group5')
            ->where("unit", "=", 'unit23')
            ->where("department", "=", 'department101')                
    })
```

For that I want to "flatten" the array in such way that I will get all the unique results as arrays:

```
arrays = [
    ['group' => 'group2', 'unit' => 'unit11', 'department' => 'department50', 'team' => 'team10'],
    ['group' => 'group2', 'unit' => 'unit11', 'department' => 'department50', 'team' => 'team58'],
    ['group' => 'group5', 'unit' => 'unit23', 'department' => 'department101'],
]
```

Because once I have these arrays, I can iterate them and query them:

```
$fullQuery = DB::table('mytable');


foreach ($arrays as $array) {
$fullQuery->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where("group", "=", $array->group)
        ->where("unit", "=", $array->unit)
        ->where("department", "=", $array->department)
        ->where("team", "=", $array->team)
    })
}
```

I've tried using a few recursive ways, but I am not good with recursion, and I was far from getting a valid result, unless there's a way to do it without recursion?

Comment: with your logic, in the loop when you call `->where("team", "=", $array->team)` it will trigger an error when a department has no team in the filter.

Comment: You are correct, I just made this query to show the general structure, but in reality, I will check if it's empty before I add the `where`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took on the challenge and made you this neat function

```
function queryBuilder($input, $column, &$finalArray, &$buildUpArray = [])
{
    $columns = ['first' => 'group', 'group' => 'unit', 'unit' => 'department', 'department' => 'team'];
    if(!isset($columns[$column])) {
        return;
    }
    $column = $columns[$column];
    foreach ($input as $key => $item) {
        $tempArray = $buildUpArray;
        if (!is_array($item) || !$item) {
            $tempArray[$column] = !$item ? $key : $item;
            $finalArray[] = $tempArray;
        } else {
            $tempArray[$column] = $key;
            queryBuilder($item, $column,$finalArray, $tempArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Dont mind the arbitrary `first` or `$columns` array, I had to shove the columns names somewhere.

You can use it like this

```
$filters = [];
queryBuilder($inputs, 'first', $filters);

foreach ($filters as $filter) {
    $query->orWhere($filter);
}
```

Here is a [Demo of the function returns](https://onlinephp.io/c/8ee03)

Comment: that's really awesome, I had to change a few things, for example instead of using it with `$query-orWhere($filter);`, I changed to `$query->orWhere(function($query) use ($filter) { $query->where($filter);});` because I needed `or` between each condition but `and` for each row